# How to add an array to listview

Tags: c#, arrays

```
item1.SubItems.Add(varintx[x]);
// my code //
```

> ERROR CS1503  C# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to "System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem"

How to add a `"int array"` like a subitem of a listview

Comment: Use `varintx[x].ToString()`

Comment: the error message clearly tells you what the issue is, `cannot convert` Convert being the key word , from `into to ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem` doing a msdn search on the error or google would tell you the data type that SubItem is expecting.. I would refresh yourself on the `.ToString() extension method as well as the `Convert.ToString()` method when you get a chance

Answer (score 2):

```
for (Int32 i = 0; i < varintx.Length; ++i)
{
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
    item.SubItems.Add(varintx[i].ToString());

    myListVIew.Items.Add(item);
}
```

You have to convert your `int` values to `string` before passing them to the `ListViewItem`. So your code excerpt should be rewritten as follows:

```
item1.SubItems.Add(varintx[x].ToString());
```